# Characterisation of adjunction via initial object of a comma category

Tags: category-theory

The following is a definition given in my lecture notes that I'm not sure is standard, so I'll write it out:
Given a functor $G: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ and an object $x$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have the category $(x \Rightarrow \mathcal{C})$ where:

- Objects are pairs $(y, f)$ where $y \in \mathcal{D}$ and $f: x \to G(y)$;
- Morphisms $(y_1, f_1) \to (y_2, f_2)$ are $\mathcal{D}$-morphisms $\alpha: y_1 \to y_2$ such that $G(\alpha) \circ f_1 = f_2$.

I'm trying to prove that $F \dashv G$ if and only if $(Fx, \eta_x)$ is initial in $(x \Rightarrow G)$ for some $\eta: \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}} \Rightarrow GF$.

I can see that any morphism $(Fx, \eta_x) \to (y, f)$ must be unique, but I am struggling to see why there should be such a morphism for every $(y, f)$ in $(x \Rightarrow G)$.

Comment: what do you mean by $F\dashv G$?

Comment: I mean F is left-adjoint to G, where F is a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$

Comment: Also, if you need it, I find really clear and linear the explanation in Leinster, "Basic category theory" (chapter 2 section 3, theorem 2.3.6 pag. 61 is what you are searching for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an object $(y,f)$, you have $f : x \to G(y)$. The adjoint transpose of $f$ is
$$\alpha := \varepsilon_y \circ F(f) : F(x) \to y$$
Moreover
$$\begin{align}
G(\alpha) \circ \eta_x &= G(\varepsilon_y) \circ GF(f) \circ \eta_x && \text{by definition of } \alpha \\
&= G(\varepsilon_y) \circ \eta_{G(y)} \circ f && \text{by naturality of } \eta \\
&= f && \text{by the triangular identities}
\end{align}$$

So $\alpha$ defines a morphism $(Fx,\eta_x) \to (y,f)$ in the comma category.